# Pandas: inverting query string produces invalid results

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

I am trying to wrap my mind around some unexpected behaviour of pandas dataframe `query` method:

Assuming a test dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  2  2  2
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

One can select the first row with the following query expression:

```
>>> df.query('a == b == c == 1 & d == e == f == 2')
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  2  2  2
```

My aim however, is to select all rows **except** those satisfying above expression. Intuitively that should work by simply wrapping the entire expression in parenthesis and pre-pending a logical `not`. - Right?

```
>> df.query('~(a == b == c == 1 & d == e == f == 2)')
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  2  2  2
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Clearly that is not the expected result. If one however draws the `not` into the expression with a little algebra, the whole thing does work:

```
>>> df.query('~(a == b == c == 1) | ~(d == e == f == 2)')
   a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Can anybody explain to me what is going on here? Clearly the last two query strings are logically identical but they still return different results.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? The second example (what gives the unexpected output) works for me (pandas 0.15.1)

Comment: @joris I was using the anaconda python distribution. Its standard version for pandas is currently 0.14.1. After updating to 0.15.1 the problem disappears. Thanks.